# How do I 'forward' (mouse) events to a node/shape on a lower Zindex in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm working with kineticjs where I have a stage with one layer in it.  This layer has multiple shapes on it who react on a mouseover event (they show a tooltip)
besides these shapes I also have some text nodes on a higher ZIndex (so they are above the shapes).

This all works fine with one exception, when a text is on top of a shape, the shape doesn't show a tooltip I assume it's because the textnode uses the event, rather than 'forward' it, eventhough I haven't bound anything to the text node.

How can I propagate events to nodes on a lower ZIndex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd create a separate layer to put anything you dont want to register mouse events on and when you create the layer set its `listening` property to false.
You could also set the this property for the individual elements.
Here's an example using layers...

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
});

var normalLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var textLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({listening :false});

var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
});

rect.on('click', function(evt) {
    this.setFill('blue');
    normalLayer.draw();
});

normalLayer.add(rect);

var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 40,
        y: 40,
        text: 'Simple Text',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        textFill: 'yellow'
      });

textLayer.add(simpleText);

stage.add(normalLayer);
stage.add(textLayer);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MT435/
Remember the `listening` property can be set for individual elements aswell.