# How to pass an event on to the nodes below in kinetics

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

[question that is very similar but answer doesn't work in my situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901932/how-do-i-forward-mouse-events-to-a-node-shape-on-a-lower-zindex-in-kineticjs)

I have a circle and I want to pass the click event to any objects that are underneath it.

I have tried:

setting cancelbubble to false. 
setting the cirle layer to listening= false doesn't work for me because the circle is then no longer draggable.

I have made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lhenning/jgaQT/)

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 400
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var background = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var colorPentagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
      x: 80,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
      sides: 5,
      radius: 70,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 4,
      draggable: true
    });
    colorPentagon.on('click', function(evt){ alert("pentagon");});

    var linearGradPentagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
      x: 360,
      y: stage.height()/2,
      sides: 5,
      radius: 70,
      fillLinearGradientStartPoint: {x:-50, y:-50},
      fillLinearGradientEndPoint: {x:50,y:50},
      fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 1, 'yellow'],
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 4,
      draggable: true
    });
    linearGradPentagon.on('click', function(evt){ alert("pentagon");});

    var radialGradPentagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
      x: 500,
      y: stage.height()/2,
      sides: 5,
      radius: 70,
      fillRadialGradientEndRadius: 70,
      fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 0.5, 'yellow', 1, 'blue'],
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 4,
      draggable: true
    });
    radialGradPentagon.on('click', function(evt){ alert("pentagon");});

    background.add(colorPentagon);
    //background.add(patternPentagon);
    background.add(linearGradPentagon);
    background.add(radialGradPentagon);
    stage.add(background);


  var hideCircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.width()/2,
    y: stage.height()/2,
    radius: 650,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1000,
      draggable:true
  });

 hideCircle.on('click', function(evt){ alert("click");});


  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(hideCircle);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
```

Currently to get it to work I have to take the click coordinates and do my own detection.  It works but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Does your design permit simply turning off event listening on the nodes you don't want to respond to events:  `myNode.listening(false)`.  Then the event will fall through to nodes underneath myNode.

Comment: No. If I turn off listening then the circle is not draggable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how to pass your click event to the bottom layer nodes:**

- You can listen for clicks on the stage
- Determine if the click is inside any node on the bottom layer
- If the click was inside a node, fire the click event on that node.

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/sFX8y/

```
stage.on('contentClick',function(e){

    // get the mouse position
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();

    // fetch the node on the bottom layer that is under the mouse, if any.
    var hitThisNode=background.getIntersection(pos);

    // if a node was hit, fire the click event on that node
    if(hitThisNode){
        hitThisNode.fire("click",e,true);
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks like the answer I am looking for but I can't get it to work in my fiddle. 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lhenning/jgaQT/4/) 
What am I doing differently.   Nevermind I figured it out problem was between keyboard and chair